# How to clone a structure with unexported field?

Tags: go, struct, clone

If I have a type defined as:

```
type T struct {
    S  string
    is []int
}
```

then how can I go about cloning an object of this type? If I do a simple assignment:

```
p := T{"some string", []int{10, 20}}
q := p
```

Then any changes made to the `[]int` affect both objects. Since `T.is` is not exported, it cannot be copied over explicitly, even if extracted using reflect.

I'm currently supplying a `Clone` method in the package of the type itself. But that doesn't help with similar types in other packages. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't. That's the point of unexported fields: only the declaring package can modify them.

Note that if the `T` type is declared in another package, you can't even write:

```
p := somepackage.T{"some string", []int{10, 20}}
```

because this would implicitly try to set the unexported `T.is` field and thus results in a compile-time error:

```
implicit assignment of unexported field 'is' in somepackage.T literal
```

If you own (or you can modify) the package, best is to provide a `Clone()` method or function, or provide a `SetIs()` method for the type `T`. If a 3rd party package does not provide such functionality, there's nothing you can do about it.

<sup>Note that using package [`unsafe`](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/) it is possible to do such things, but as its name says: it's *unsafe* and you should stay away from it.</sup>

Also note that you can create new values of `T` where `is` is not copied but will be the [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) of its type (which in case of `[]int` will be `nil`):

```
var r somepackage.T
s := somepackage.T{S: p.S}

fmt.Printf("%q\n", r)
fmt.Printf("%q\n", s)
```

Which will output:

```
{"" []}
{"some string" []}
```

But you can't set any non-zero value for the unexported field `T.is`.

Do note that you can make "exact" copies of structs having unexported fields by simply [assigning](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments) them to another struct variable (of the same type), which will properly copy the unexported fields too.

Like in this example:

```
type person struct {
    Name string
    age  *int
}

age := 22
p := &person{"Bob", &age}
fmt.Println(p)

p2 := new(person)
*p2 = *p
fmt.Println(p2)
```

Which will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/tKkRC3IeT2t)):

```
&{Bob 0x414020}
&{Bob 0x414020}
```

Which we can even generalize using `reflect` without relying on the concrete type:

```
type person struct {
    Name string
    age  *int
}

age := 22
p := &person{"Bob", &age}
fmt.Println(p)

v := reflect.ValueOf(p).Elem()
vp2 := reflect.New(v.Type())
vp2.Elem().Set(v)
fmt.Println(vp2)
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/wmSD3iuptp3).

**But what we can't do** is change the `person.age` unexported field to point to something else. Without help of the declaring package, it can only be `nil` or the same pointer value (pointing to the object as the original field).