# Exporting functions with anonymous struct as a parameter [cannot use value (type struct {...}) as type struct {...} in argument to package.Func]

Tags: go, struct, anonymous-types

Here is a piece of code <kbd>[play.google.org](https://play.golang.org/p/nk9HBJAMO3)</kbd> that runs without any problem:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func PrintAnonymous(v struct {
    i int
    s string
}) {
    fmt.Printf("%d: %s\n", v.i, v.s)
}

func PrintAnonymous2(v struct{}) {
    fmt.Println("Whatever")
}

func main() {
    value := struct {
        i int
        s string
    }{
        0, "Hello, world!",
    }
    PrintAnonymous(value)
    PrintAnonymous2(struct{}{})
}
```

However, if the `PrintAnonymous()` function exists in another package (let's say, `temp`), the code will not work:

```
cannot use value (type struct { i int; s string })
as type struct { i int; s string } in argument to temp.PrintAnonymous
```

My question are:

- Is there a way to call a (public) function with anonymous struct as a parameter (a.k.a. `PrintAnonymous()` above)?
- A function with empty struct as a parameter (a.k.a. `PrintAnonymous2()` above) can be called even if it exists in another package. Is this a special case?

Well, I know that I can always name the `struct` to solve the problem, I'm just curious about this, and wonder why it seems that this is not allowed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The fields of your anonymous struct type are unexported. This means you cannot create values of this struct and specify values for the fields from another package. [Spec: Composite literals:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals)

> It is an error to specify an element for a non-exported field of a struct belonging to a different package.

If you change the struct definition to export the fields, then it will work because all fields can be assigned to by other packages (see Siu Ching Pong -Asuka Kenji-'s answer).

This is the case with the empty struct (with no fields) too: the empty struct has no fields, thus it has no unexported fields, so you're allowed to pass a value of that.

You can call the function with unmodified struct (with unexported fields) via [reflection](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) though. You can obtain the [`reflect.Type`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type) of the `PrintAnonymous()` function, and you can use `Type.In()` to get the `reflect.Type` of its first parameter. That is the anonymous struct we want to pass a value for. And you can construct a value of that type using [`reflect.New()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#New). This will be a [`reflect.Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type), wrapping a pointer to the [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) of the anonymous struct. Sorry, you can't have a struct value with fields having non-zero values (for reason mentioned above).

This is how it could look like:

```golang
v := reflect.ValueOf(somepackage.PrintAnonymous)
paramt := v.Type().In(0)
v.Call([]reflect.Value{reflect.New(paramt).Elem()})
```

This will print:

```
0:
```

`0` is zero value for `int`, and `""` empty string for `string`.

For deeper inside into the type system and structs with unexported fields, see related questions:

**[Identify non builtin-types using reflect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36310538/identify-non-builtin-types-using-reflect)**
**[How to clone a structure with unexported field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38369350/how-to-clone-a-structure-with-unexported-field)**

---

Interestingly (*this is a bug*, see linked issue below), using reflection, you can use a value of your own anonymous struct type (with matching, unexported fields), and in this case we can use values other than the zero value of the struct fields:

```golang
value := struct {
    i int
    s string
}{
    1, "Hello, world!",
}

v.Call([]reflect.Value{reflect.ValueOf(value)})
```

Above runs (without panic):

```
1: Hello, world!
```

The reason why this is allowed is due to a bug in the compiler. See the example code below:

```
s := struct{ i int }{2}

t := reflect.TypeOf(s)
fmt.Printf("Name: %q, PkgPath: %q\n", t.Name(), t.PkgPath())
fmt.Printf("Name: %q, PkgPath: %q\n", t.Field(0).Name, t.Field(0).PkgPath)

t2 := reflect.TypeOf(subplay.PrintAnonymous).In(0)
fmt.Printf("Name: %q, PkgPath: %q\n", t2.Name(), t2.PkgPath())
fmt.Printf("Name: %q, PkgPath: %q\n", t2.Field(0).Name, t2.Field(0).PkgPath)
```

Output is:

```
Name: "", PkgPath: ""
Name: "i", PkgPath: "main"
Name: "", PkgPath: ""
Name: "i", PkgPath: "main"
```

As you can see the unexported field `i` in both anonymous struct types (in `main` package and in `somepackage` as parameter to `PrintAnonymous()` function) –falsely– report the same package, and thus their type will be equal:

```golang
fmt.Println(t == t2) // Prints true
```

Note: I consider this a *flaw*: if this is allowed using reflection, then this should be possible without using reflection too. If without reflection the compile-time error is justified, then using reflection should result in runtime panic. I opened an issue for this, you can follow it here: [issue #16616](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/16616). Fix currently aims Go 1.8.

Answer (score 7):

Oh! I just realized that the field names are in lowercase, and thus not public! Changing the first letter of the field names to uppercase solves the problem:

```golang
package main

import (
    "temp"
)

func main() {
    value := struct {
        I int
        S string
    }{
        0, "Hello, world!",
    }
    temp.PrintAnonymous(value)
    temp.PrintAnonymous2(struct{}{})
}
```

```golang
package temp

import (
    "fmt"
)

func PrintAnonymous(v struct{I int; S string}) {
    fmt.Printf("%d: %s\n", v.I, v.S)
}

func PrintAnonymous2(v struct{}) {
    fmt.Println("Whatever")
}
```