# Deep copying data structures in golang

Tags: go, struct, deep-copy

I want to duplicate an instance of a data structure. Since go does not have any builtins, I am using a third party library: `https://github.com/emirpasic/gods`.

For example, I may try use deep copy with a hash set.

```
var c, d hashset.Set
c = *hashset.New()
c.Add(1)
deepcopy.Copy(d, c)
c.Add(2)
fmt.Println(c.Contains(2))
fmt.Println(d.Contains(2))
fmt.Println(c.Contains(1))
fmt.Println(d.Contains(1))
```

However, the content of the hash set is not copied at all. I know deep copy modules can't copy unexported values, but since there is no builtin "copy constructor" in the library, does it mean it is not possible to fully duplicate a data structure instance with the library without modifying its code? (Similar problem happens with some other libraries I looked into).

I am new to golang and does not feel right, since similar things can be easily achieved for example in C++. I know I could write my own version or modify their code, but it is too much work than expected and that's why I think there should be an idiomatic way.

PS: For people who may say "there is no need of such functionality", I am distributing some complex state with some data structures to parallel calculation threads, they use the states directly and must not interfere with each other.

Comment: Using package `reflect` you should be able to implement your own deep copy including unexported fields using `unsafe`, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @mkopriva: but that sounds like a lot of work out of nothing :) Having an abilitiy to deep-copy all fields does indeed appear useful.

Comment: @mkopriva You can read unexported fields using reflection, but you can't set them. See [How to clone a structure with unexported field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38369350/how-to-clone-a-structure-with-unexported-field)

Comment: @icza https://stackoverflow.com/a/43918797/965900 (i did mention `unsafe` in my initial comment)

Comment: @mkopriva Yes, using `unsafe` you can do anything, even modify immutable strings, so I wouldn't count that.

Comment: @mkopriva Oh, sorry, didn't spot the `unsafe` word in your first comment.

Comment: @icza no problem at all

Comment: There's a library that does it now super easy via `deep.Copy` (or `deep.MustCopy`): https://github.com/brunoga/deep

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unfortunately or not, there is no way to do this in Go. First tool that comes to mind is reflection (package [`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/)), but using reflection you can only read unexported fields, but you can't set them. See [How to clone a structure with unexported field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38369350/how-to-clone-a-structure-with-unexported-field)

The only way to clone structures with unexported fields would be to use package [`unsafe`](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/) (see an example here: [Access unexported fields in golang/reflect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42664837/access-unexported-fields-in-golang-reflect/43918797#43918797)), but as its name says: it's *unsafe* and you should stay away from it as much as possible. Programs created using `unsafe` has no guarantee that they continue to work with newer Go releases, or that they behave the same on every platform.

*In general* the only and proper way to support cloning in Go is if the package itself supports such operations.

**Note #1:**

This does not mean that in some *specific* case you can't "mimic" cloning by creating a new value and building its state manually. For example you can clone a `map` by creating a new map, iterating over the key-value pairs of the original and setting them in the new map.

**Note #2:**

Do note that you can make "exact" copies of structs having unexported fields by simply [assigning](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments) them to another struct variable (of the same type), which will properly copy the unexported fields too.

Like in this example:

```
type person struct {
    Name string
    age  *int
}

age := 22
p := &person{"Bob", &age}
fmt.Println(p)

p2 := new(person)
*p2 = *p
fmt.Println(p2)
```

Which will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/tKkRC3IeT2t)):

```
&{Bob 0x414020}
&{Bob 0x414020}
```

Which we can even generalize using `reflect` without relying on the concrete type:

```
type person struct {
    Name string
    age  *int
}

age := 22
p := &person{"Bob", &age}
fmt.Println(p)

v := reflect.ValueOf(p).Elem()
vp2 := reflect.New(v.Type())
vp2.Elem().Set(v)
fmt.Println(vp2)
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/wmSD3iuptp3).

**But what we can't do** is change the `person.age` unexported field to point to something else. Without help of the declaring package, it can only be `nil` or the same pointer value (pointing to the object as the original field).

Also see related: [Quicker way to deepcopy objects in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46790190/quicker-way-to-deepcopy-objects-in-golang)

Comment: There's also a library now that does it in one line via `deep.Copy` (or `deep.MustCopy`): https://github.com/brunoga/deep

Answer (score 9):

If your struct is serializable, you can convert it to JSON and back, which was good enough for my use case.

```
func CloneMyStruct(orig *model.MyStruct) (*model.MyStruct, error) {
    origJSON, err := json.Marshal(orig)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    clone := model.MyStruct{}
    if err = json.Unmarshal(origJSON, &clone); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return &clone, nil
}
```

Comment: Deep copy via JSON works, but in my case it was almost 10 times slower compared to a custom-built function for the specific data structure.

Comment: Yup, that sounds about right. This way of copying is prioritizing ease-of-use over performance.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to deep copy a protobuf struct, you can use `proto.Clone` in `https://github.com/golang/protobuf`, see [godoc](https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto) for more help.

Answer (score 2):

[Reprint library](https://github.com/qdm12/reprint) has proper support of deep copying including copying unexported fields.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/qdm12/reprint"
)

type Test struct {
    field []int
}

func main() {
    orig := Test{field: []int{1, 2}}
    copy := reprint.This(orig).(Test)
    orig.field[0] = 3
    fmt.Println("orig", orig.field[0])
    fmt.Println("copy", copy.field[0])
}
```

Comment: That was really simple and no use of tricks with JSON or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If the package your are using does not provide a copy function for the data stucture, then I would write my own type-safe copy function. Moreover, I would not worry about unexported fields, because there must be a reason why the developer has decided to hide those fields to users.

In your example:

```
func NewHashSetCopy(src *hashset.Set) *hashset.Set{
    dst := *hashset.New()
    iterator := src.Iter()
    for elem := range iterator {
        dst.Add(elem)
    }
    return dst
}
```

Comment: It has been my experience that, in many cases, unexported fields are such because the developer has not considered the deep-copying use case (or, potentially, has consciously decided not to provide for it, and generally not documented the reason for that decision). There are absolutely cases where (short of using `unsafe`), there is no way to make a valid deep copy because some crucial field is not exported and the package does not provide a built-in mechanism for copying.